# capturing a browser refreshed event using Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am writing a program to automate link validations in a site. Our site is having more than 400 links per page and we need to open each link and see it is returning a valid page i.e 200, there are other requirements as well to check if the page is a 404 redirection page etc. It means to validate 400 inks it will take about 30 minutes or so.

My design is to integrate this with the Front-End (Selenium) automation in a way that each time the browser loads a new page or browser refreshes it will trigger a new thread by passing the page source for validating all the href available.

We are not following a page object model otherwise I could trigger this in my each page.

Question here is that is there any way we can listen to a browser refresh or page load event using Selenium Web Driver?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I don't understand your question, but page_refresh and page_load_event can be two very different goals for you, if you are dealing with AJAX. You can try [this article](http://www.seleniumwebdriver.com/google-selenium-webdriver/how-to-know-if-a-page-has-been-reloaded-after-some-ajax-refresh/) about the AJAX part
and this one for [selenium custom events synchronization](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/selenium-synchronization-with-custom-events).

This [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398203/how-to-check-if-refresh-page-event-occurs-or-not-after-an-ui-event-ex-click-on) is the most actual I could find.

Actually Selenium is JS driver so this answers can be helpful if you want to try it too:

- [check-if-page-reloaded-or-refresh-in-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-reloaded-or-refresh-in-js)
- [is-page-reloaded-or-refreshed-using-jquery-or-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400182/how-to-check-page-is-reloading-or-refreshing-using-jquery-or-javascript)
- [post_detect_refresh_with_javascript](http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_detect_refresh_with_javascript.php)

Comment: My objective is to get the page load with a browser refresh, not an Ajax Load. Once the DOM is ready I am going to use the complete HTML source and parse to identify the hrefs in it. I want to make it as a background process with a single method, that the reason I was thinking about a listener. However I am going to try out the options you have provided since I guess there is no direct method available to use