# How to check if refresh page event occurs or not after clicking submit button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I am using PHPunit + Selenium WebDriver .In one of the testcase , I need to do html form validation (checking all required fields are filled or not) this requires me to check whether page refresh event occurs or not after I submit my form ..

Note: I tried implementing the below link (solution-2) but phpunit is throwing sytax error-unexpected  'jsExecutor'
[How to check if refresh page event occurs or not after an UI event (ex. click on a button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398203/how-to-check-if-refresh-page-event-occurs-or-not-after-an-ui-event-ex-click-on)

Please help me

Comment: [Look here, may be it's useful to you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637123/selenium-ide-how-to-verify-assert-page-refresh

Comment: @rajanasekhar : I want to check on page refresh event particularly

Comment: Does anything change in the source code when the page is refreshed? If so you could try comparing the initial source code to the (presumably) new source code.